# What are the operational links between exponential and weibull distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution, weibull-distribution

I recently read a [very interesting article](https://statisticalhorizons.com/for-causal-analysis-of-competing-risks/) about competing risks that came with simulations.

In these, the author defines a Weibull distributed variable `w` using an exponential random variable. He also set a dependency on a random normal variable `x`.

Here is the SAS code he used:

```
data finegraytest;
do i=1 to 10000;
*Generate x, standard normal;
  x=rannor(0);
*Generate w with Weibull distribution depending on x;
  logw=2 + -.75*x + 1.5*log(ranexp(0));
  w=exp(logw);
```

Here is the translation in R if needed:

```r
#Generate x, standard normal
x = rnorm(n)
#Generate w with Weibull distribution depending on x;
logw = 2 + -.75*x + 1.5*log(rexp(n)),
w = exp(logw),
```

I'm trying to understand this construction better: what would be the parameters (scale/shape) of the distribution of `w`? The dependency on `x` is of lower importance to me, although including it in an answer would be a plus.

So far, I think I understood that the scale parameter should be `1.5` (multiplicative on `log(rexp(n))`), as the rate parameter of `logw` could have been `1/1.5` for the same results. However, I could not figure out how this work if the shape is not 1.

I tried playing with the distribution functions of exponential and Weibull distribution but could not figure out anything either.

Comment: A Weibull distributed random variable is a power of an exponentially distributed random variable.  In particular, if $X \sim Exp(1)$ then $W=\lambda \, {X}^{1/k}$ has a Weibull distribution with shape parameter $k$ and scale parameter $\lambda$

Comment: @Henry Thanks that's exactly what I wanted to know! How would I find this myself? Could this be inferred from the distribution functions?

Comment: Looking at the two densities or even more the CDFs, it is fairly clear that a simple change of variables will work to prove this

Comment: @Henry Thanks but please understand that I have little to no formal training in maths, which is why I'm asking here (cf. the last sentence of my question). Moreover, I have difficulties grasping the concepts linking variable generation to actual math formulas. Also, since this seems trivial to you, would you mind explaining the normal variable `x`, does it change anything about this?

Comment: If  $X \sim Exp(1)$ then $W=\exp(2 + 1.5 \log(X)) = e^2 X^{1.5}$ has a Weibull distribution with shape parameter $1.5$  and scale parameter $e^2$.  The other term has the effect of multiplying this by a lognormally distributed factor - I have no idea as to why you might want to do this